# jQuery not let me submit all inputs of a form after the .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding number of inputs to my html form using jQuery .append(). I am trying to submit inputs using arrays but it does not recognize the appended input fields. If I append those statically it will work:

The input fields look like this:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8888/xxx/action.php" method="post" id="form">
                        <div class="row noMargin" id="question1">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-4  " id="">
                            <input type="text" class="qnaQ form-control" id="qnaQ" name="qnaQ[]">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-2  " id="">
                                <input type="text" class="qnaOpt1 form-control" id="qnaOpt1" name="qnaA1[]">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-2  " id="">
                                <input type="text" class="qnaOpt2 form-control" id="qnaOpt2" name="qnaA2[]">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-2  " id="">
                                <input type="text" class="qnaOpt3 form-control" id="qnaOpt2" name="qnaA3[]">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-2  " id="">
                                <input type="text" class="qnaOpt4 form-control" id="qnaOpt4" name="qnaA4[]">
                            </div>


                            <div class="row noMargin topPadding">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-2 " id="">
                                    Correct Answer:
                                </div>
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Answer<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Option3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Option4</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

The script that adds more field:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var currentItem = 1;
            $('#addQna').click(function(){
                currentItem++;
                $('#items').val(currentItem);
                var strToAdd ='<div class="row noMargin topPadding" id="question1"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-4" id=""><input type="text" class="qnaQ form-control" id="qnaQ" name="qnaQ[]"></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-2  " id=""><input type="text" class="qnaOpt1 form-control" id="qnaOpt1" name="qnaA1[]"></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-2" id=""><input type="text" class="qnaOpt2 form-control" id="qnaOpt2" name="qnaA2[]"></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-2" id=""><input type="text" class="qnaOpt3 form-control" id="qnaOpt3" name="qnaA3[]"></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-2" id=""><input type="text" class="qnaOpt4 form-control" id="qnaOpt4" name="qnaA4[]"></div><div class="row noMargin topPadding"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-2" id="">Correct Answer:</div><div class="btn-group"><a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Answer<span class="caret"></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="#">Option1</a></li><li><a href="#">Option2</a></li><li><a href="#">Option3</a></li><li><a href="#">Option4</a></li></ul></div></div></div>';

                $('#questions').append(strToAdd);

            });
});
</script>
```

The button that submits the form to the php:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default saveTraining" id="saveTraining">
        Save
    </button>
```

Comment: can you add a jsFiddle to your question?

Comment: I think there is missing information to answer your question, do you have all inside a form tags?, where is the div `#questions` in the html?

Comment: Probably you appending your questions to `div` which outside `form` element.

Answer (score 2):

try to add `form` attribute to the `input` tag with the form id :

```
<input ... form="form-id">
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the same id more than once.
What I could understand there, when you append a new question, the ids and names of the texts are the same, and with this, the post its not going to recognize all the values.

Comment: Yes but if I just copy and paste the chunk that .append adds it will work. So that is not the problem.

Comment: Ok. Where is the element with the id=questions ? Are you appending to an element not defined..